# Is there a word to refer to "changing TV channels"?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

I wrote the following sentence:

> As if she had just realized it was there, she grabbed the remote
>   control from the table, turned on the TV, and **changed the channel** to
>   the news.

I'm not a native English-speaker, but I think there was a word for "changing the channel."

Is there one?

Comment: In my family, we *click*, with the *clicker*. Failing that, we just *go* to the news, or *went* in the past.

Comment: Why do you want a word for this? There is nothing wrong with using "changed the channel". There is no ambiguity about it. It is perfectly clear what it means.

Comment: I always liked _surfing_ for the choosing of channels. I.E. "She _surfed_ over to the news." Very visual word. Alternatively, avoid the rather passive activity altogether and simply imply the action has occurred. "I don't now how it happened or why but the next thing I knew the remote was in her hand and we were watching the news." Of course that's more Writers than EL&U, but I digress.

Comment: @Jed Oliver It's a third person narrative novel I'm writing.

Comment: You can also "click to the news" just as well as "switch to the news".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Not really; *channel-changing* is not a verb.

You could just say they *switched* to the news, or turned the news on.

Comment: *Switched* is the answer, despite what the other answers would have people believe.

Comment: @Rob, but "zapped" implies using the "remote control device", "switched" does not.

Comment: Use of the remote in the OP's example is explicit. Moreover, in this day and age, use of a remote to switch channels is implied. I can't even remember the last time I saw someone get up and change channels manually—decades ago, perhaps?

Comment: @Robus, perhaps; however you can switch a lot of things, but, as the dictionaries say, I assure you that "zap" is more specific to this case.

Comment: @Carlo_R *zap* is more specific to the action, but both less formal, and perhaps too focused on the mechanism of the action - do we care that she used a remote, or turned on the television with the intention of seeing the news. If the context is that she expects something to be on the news (a recent relevant event) or that she is a regular viewer of the news, then *zapped* would be inferior in focusing on the use of a remote control, rather than on the news being her reason for turning on the television.

Comment: @Carlo: Oh, you *assure* me. Well, that's very different. Let me assure *you* that dictionaries list many different meanings of *zap*. In other words, you can zap a lot of other things as well: you can switch things and you can zap things. So what exactly is the point you're making?

Comment: @Robus, but the Oxford Dictionary of English says: "_zap_, use a remote control to change television channels." Do you think of having enough authority to deny the OED?

Comment: There's what's in dictionaries and there's how people actually talk. If you only get your information from dictionaries, you're missing a crucial element of understanding.

Comment: @Carlo_R.: Yes, I think Robusto has way more authority than the OED at least in this case, being a self-reflective native speaker. Dictionaries, even the best of them  like the OED, don't give the relative frequency of a word for each context. 'zap' may have been common at one time or in some subcultures, but it certainly isn't used at all nowadays (and frankly I've _never_ heard it used in that context).

Comment: @Carlo_R.: We've been here before. OED lists *to zap* primarily because many people call the remote control itself a *zapper*. But in practice, an individual instance of using the zapper to re-tune is just called *switching* or *changing* channel (doing that several times in a short period is called *channel-hopping*). The verb *to zap* is becoming less common with TV remotes these days (it was an "exotic" coinage from back in the days when it was new / exciting / sophisticated technology).

Comment: @tchrist: Just as you can *switch **to*** the news, you can *switch **on*** the news. That latter still slightly implies the TV wasn't previously on at all - but less than it used to, I think. I certainly don't find anything odd in being asked to ***put** the news on*, irrespective of whether the TV is currently on or not. Changing channels is now virtually so trivial in the context of remotes that the fact of *changing* is barely worth mentioning unless you want to emphasise ***stop** watching **this**, and **start** watching **that***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Sure, you can put the news on. That’s fine, too. However, it may underplay that you’re switching from one channel to another.

Comment: @tchrist: That's my point. In many contexts, even if the TV is currently *on*, that's scarcely relevant. It's not like when I was growing up (only 2 channels in the UK, and even they only broadcast for maybe 8 hours a day). Today lots of people leave the TV on with the sound muted. To me, the only difference the "current" channel makes is that if my permanently-on tivo-equivalent setup happens to be on the right channel I can "rewind" back to the start of the news. If it's not, I'll have to switch to something like BBC News 24, or take note of the clock time (which I hate doing nowadays! :)

Answer (score 8):

In addition to "*switched* to the news", "*flipped*(over) to the news" can be used idiomatically here, although I think it is slightly informal (and relatively rare, see edit).

"Zap" is also apparently a word of the meaning you're looking for, as stated in other answers, but I haven't heard it used in everyday speech.

In addition to that, because, in this case, the television has only just been turned on, I think saying "*put/switched on* the news" would also work, without making reference to the channel being changed.

Edit: As per one of the comments on this answer, it appears that "flipped over" is very rarely used in *writing* (which is what you're looking for); I based this off what I have heard used in everyday *speech*, and this also comes with the caveat that it may be more specific to the UK, or maybe even the Midlands. I also note that "flicked" is also used in this way, but with similarly low frequency. "Switched" appears to be the more common term at any rate.

Comment: +1 for *flipped*; *zapped* seems old-fashioned to me, and is usualy something done with a microwave rather than a television, at least among my peers.

Comment: Searching Google Books for [flipped to the news **channel**](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22flipped+to+the+news+channel%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) turns up just 3 hits, compared to 76 for "switched". And there are still only 10 hits for "flipped" even if we remove "channel" from the search term, but that gives thousands of hits for the "switched" version. Okay, "flip" and "zap" are comprehensible. But they're not exactly the terms of choice.

Comment: I'm going to leave "flipped" in as it is definitely something I hear used quite often and it still brings in some results, although I've edited to explain that this may be a. localised and b. more common in speech.

Answer (score 2):

Zap: v. To use a remote control device to switch (channels on a television) or to turn off (a television set).

So, you can say: "... zapped to the news."

Reference: American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fourth Edition

Comment: Yes, *zap*. I checked on [Wordnik][link] and found the following definition for *zap*: >To use a remote control device to switch (channels on a television) or to turn off (a television set). [link]: http://www.wordnik.com/words/zap

Comment: *switched* to the news.  *surfed* to the news.

Comment: I've never heard *zapped* used in the context of switching channels, only switching a set off.

Comment: I have never heard *zap* applied to a remote control, full stop.

Comment: I haven't heard "zapped" used at all. It sounds odd and colloquial. Is it something specific to American English?

Comment: *Zap* is the French expression. I've never heard it in the US.

Comment: @Tristan: it's not AmE as far as I know. Maybe from a much older  generation?

Comment: It definitely sounds like it is some kind of slang, used by certain people as an alternative and not something that is used generally. It could be from older generations. It's not used by English and other British people.

Comment: @Tristan I can’t speak for the other 350 million people who live here, but I’ve never heard it used that way in North America.  Can’t say I’ve spent much time in Québec though, so maybe it happens there amongst the non-English speakers.

Comment: @tchrist I'm a French speaker living in Quebec and I've heard and used this expression meaning *to quickly switch between channels with a remote*. Something you couldn't do before TV sets had remote controls. I didn't know this was only a French expression but judging from the comments here that may be the case. The expression could also be a bit dated, I'm not really sure.

Comment: @Alexandre, yes, this is the way I know this word: "to quickly switch between channels with a remote", but on EL&U the majority of people speaks American or British English.

Comment: @Tristan I'm also British and "zapping" is the first word that came to my mind. I don't remember exactly where I first heard zap used in this context, but it was almost certainly on British television. I moved from England about 15 years ago, so it may have fallen out of use.

Comment: Chris, which region of the UK was that used in?

Answer (score -2):

I would say SWAP CHANNELS or SWAP BETWEEN CHANNELS not that is something wrong with change or switched but I think swap is a word that you learn at advance levels so you will sound more proficient in English

Comment: *Swapping* involves exchanging. Changing from channel A to channel B does not swap the two channels.